# Copy and paste files through clipboard in Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, clipboard, copy-paste

In the folder E:\Files there are 2 files, which I want to copy and paste into D:\Dest:

E:\Files\

- File1.txt
- File2.txt

Using the keyboard I would simply select the 2 files, push ctrl+c, and in the destination folder D:\Dest\ I then push ctrl+v.

Now I want to achieve this using Powershell. So I copy the files into the clipboard:

```
Set-Clipboard -Path E:\Files\*
```

But how to paste those files now into the destination folder? Obviously, I will need `Get-Clipboard`. But it's not quite clear to me, how to use it, in order to paste the files.

I know I could copy the contents of these 2 files and then by using `Set-Content` create those files in D:\Dest\ on my own and copy the content into them. But is there any direct way? Because with `Set-Clipboard` those files already are in the clipboard. They just need to be pasted. I can use ctrl+v and it works. But I want to paste them through Powershell. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a special reason for using clipboard? Otherwise I suggest to use [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1) which is more efficient.

Comment: I'm working with a bunch of remote computers where I need to exchange files. With `Copy-Item` I need to address a specific computer. But with the clipboard no specific computer needs to be addressed ahead. I simply copy the files into the clipboard from my local computer. And every remote computer, which reads the clipboard, will get the files. In my context it's not always clear, which remote computers will have to get the files.

Comment: How are you working with the remote computers? It would be helpful if you could give more context so we could find a better solution than the clipboard. With `Set-Clipboard` you only copy the local paths. I don't see how the remote computers are supposed to get access to your local clipboard and work with these local paths, which have no meaning for them.

Comment: Ditto to what 'zett42' said. It seems that you are saying, remote computers are accessing your host clipboard? How are they doing this? Outside of the security implications, meaning if a remote user can access your clipboard at any time without your knowledge as well as your clipboard having nefarious code. Well, just say'in. I'd never trust this. If I were your risk management/security team, we'd be in a very long sit down about this. Why not just drop the files on a remote file share and have them get it from there? You can automate drop.

Comment: With RDP you can choose to use certain resources in your remote session, among others the clipboard. It's quite a common practice to share the clipboard, IMHO. You can do it with remote sessions, you can do it with subsystems. Why shouldn't it be possible? I don't see any security issue as I'm the only one accessing those remote computers. 
But according to what you write, I assume that there is no easy way to simply paste files into a specified directory with Powershell. So thanks for your contributions. I'll go for a different way and reconsider the whole thing.

Comment: Another reason for using the clipboard is Citrix desktops. My remote Citrix desktop doesn't allow PowerShell remoting, but it can access my local clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Before PowerShell 6 (when Get-Clipboard -Format was dropped), to paste files/directories:

```
$fileDrop = get-clipboard -Format FileDropList 
if($fileDrop -eq $null)
{
    write-host "No files on the clipboard"
    return
}

foreach($file in $fileDrop)
{
    if($file.Mode.StartsWith("d"))
    {
        $source = join-path $file.Directory $file.Name
        $e = "copy-item -Recurse $source $($file.Name)"
        $e
        Invoke-Expression $e
    }
    else
    {
        $file.Name
        $file | copy-item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the .NET `Clipboard` class:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$files = [System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection]::new()
$files.Add('YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE')

[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetFileDropList($files)
```

This copies `YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE` to the local clipboard.

You could use this, for example, when you're in a local terminal and need to copy file(s) to a remote session without PowerShell remoting (e.g., RDP or Citrix) without opening the directory in Explorer.

It's a little unwieldy, so if I used it a lot, I'd probably put it in a function like `Copy-FileToClipboard` and add it to my PowerShell profile.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the other comment in this thread, but refactored, and supporting both move and copy actions (moving is the default action, while copying is achieved with the `-c` parameter). The script pastes clipboard files and folders into the current directory (I have placed it in a `PATH` directory and use it as `paste`).

```
$data = Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList 

if ($data -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($file in $data)
    {
        if ($args[0] -eq "-c")
        {
            $action = "Copied:"
            Copy-Item -Recurse -LiteralPath $file
        }
        else
        {
            $action = "Moved:"
            Move-Item -LiteralPath $file
        }
        
        $action
        "- from: $(Join-Path $file.Directory $file.Name)"
        "- into: $(Join-Path "$(Get-Location)" $file.Name)"
    }
}
```

The `-LiteralPath` parameter was needed to handle filenames containing [square brackets](https://superuser.com/questions/212808/powershell-bug-in-copy-move-rename-when-filename-contains-square-bracket-charac/212910#212910).